# Is $f(x)=\cos(\frac {1}{x})$ Lipschitz continuous in $(1, +\infty)$?

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I don't know how to prove whether $f(x)$ is or isn't Lipschitz continuous. I tried by using the definition but I can't come up to a conclusion. I'm so bad at this! xD

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** bounded derivative implies Lipschitz continuity. You can easily prove this using the mean value theorem. And then check the derivative of your function.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$f'(x)=\frac 1{x^2}\sin\frac1x\implies |f'(x)|\le 1, \forall x\in (1,\infty).$$

Comment: You made a sign mistake in the derivative.